# Inserting into postgres using concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use multithreading to insert raw_html into postgres but I can't get the data to insert and keep getting

```
LINE 1: INSERT INTO raw_html VALUES b'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"...
                                    ^

Error: syntax error at or near "b'<!DOCTYPE html
```

I can't figure out what the `b` is doing in front of each of these strings (nor can I find anything online explaining what the b is) and I am assuming that's why the insert is failing. I also am trying to get the raw_html string to convert to a tuple because I think it needs to be a tuple for sql to accept it. I can't figure out what to try next to fix these two issues. Any direction appreciated:

UPDATE:

```
def execute_values(LST):
    DB_HOST = "localhost"
    DB_NAME = "yellow_pages_scraper"
    DB_USER = "justinbenfit"
    DB_PASS = "postgres"
    DB_URL = "mydburl"

    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        LST = tuple(LST)
        for L in LST:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO raw_html VALUES (?)", (L.decode('utf-8'),))
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        return 1
    print(f"the dataframe is inserted")

def main(LINKS):
    t0 = time.time()
    download_raw(LINKS)
    execute_values(LST)
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f"{t1-t0} seconds to download {len(LST)} raw_html.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems.  First you are sending a `bytes` string instead of a Unicode string.  Second, you are not doing any quoting.  Third, your INSERT syntax is wrong; the values need to be in parens.  Fourth, you should be allowing the database to do the quoting for you, to prevent SQL arracks.

This should work:

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO raw_html VALUES (?)", (L.decode('utf-8'),)
```

However, your whole concept is flawed.  You have each thread opening a new connection into the database.  That's horrible.  The database insertion is not your bottleneck here.  You should be able to do this serially.  Just delay the `commit` until the whole set is done.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Roberts! that makes sense to just do away with the concurrency for the sql insertion and just save the conn.commit until the end of the set. I have updated the code and am a little closer I think. Am I on the right track? Still getting ```Error: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO raw_html VALUES (?)``` I have tried adding a semi-colon after the last `)` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: never mind! got it to work with this: ```cur.execute("INSERT INTO raw_html (raw_html) VALUES (%s);", (L.decode('utf-8'),))```